# How can I display image and text within one AS3 datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, actionscript-3

The following page shows how to load external images in AS3 DataGrid: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/datagrid_pt3/ (image and text are displayed in two columns)
But I wonder how the image and text can be loaded together within the same DataGrid. Within one column: Image followed by the text.
I cannot get it work so I'd be grateful for any help with examples. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just have to write a custom CellRenderer that does it. If you really read and understand that page you linked, they explain how to make custom CellRenderers, and you can put whatever you want in a cell. An image with text, a button, a game of tetris, whatever.